# Slug and generic views

Tags: python, django

i have an app called blog and blog and Post and Categories model.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ListView.as_view(
                    queryset=Post.objects.filter(category=4)[:5],
                    template_name='blog.html')),
```

i can see above code like this

127.0.0.1/categories/php/

with above url , i can see the 5 articles with category 4 . What i want i that making it dynamic.. For example, python is category 3

```
queryset=Post.objects.filter(category='P<pk>\d')[:5]
```

i tried this but does not working. Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `ListView` and add the functionality in there:

```
class BlogPostView(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.get('slug')
        slug_id = ... # code here to determine id of slug's category
        self.queryset = Post.objects.filter(category=slug_id)[:5]
        return super(BlogPostView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

with the following as URL configuration:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BlogListView.as_view()),
```

Django will only parse the URL string/regex to determine what parameters it has, you can't pass a string/regex to filter objects for a queryset.

Comment: sorry but will i use this in a view or create a custome file called BlogListView?

Comment: You should put `BlogPostView` in `views.py` and the URL configuration in `urls.py`.

Comment: url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BlogListView.as_view()), so here's wrong ? because we call BlogListView ? instead of BlogPostView.as_view()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but `BlogPostView.as_view()` is similar to `ListView.as_view(...)`, it's just that the parameters and the view are now in a separate file instead of in `urls.py`.

Comment: i just see this in your example, url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BlogListView.as_view()), but there's no BlogListView , its BlogPostView.as_view()) anyway ty for your help